# ack-grep Easter eggs - what is the meaning of ack-grep --cathy?

Tags: ack

`ack-grep` has 3 easter eggs:

```
ack-grep --thppt
ack-grep --bar 
ack-grep --cathy
```

While I am a huge fan of `ack-grep --bar` and I get `ack-grep --thppt`, could anyone explain the joke behind `ack-grep --cathy`?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbCT5fXdhhc

Comment: As interesting as this question is, I wonder if it is rather off-topic (and would have been when it was asked). I will see if it can be closed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not programming related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ ack --cathy
                +-------------+
                |  CHOCOLATE! |
                |  CHOCOLATE! |
                |  CHOCOLATE! |
                |    AACK!    |
                +-------------+
                      \                 :,.
                       \               .M~ZM~
                        \               ~D  M
                    .    \               M~.8           .MMM
                ,.        \              ~MN            +I.M.
               ?O.M:       \              O.           ~Z=N.
              . DZ.Z.       \                         =MM.
               . .~MM.       \                        ~
                    M.               .7NM.
                    .      :M NNMMM MMNM   DMMMMMM=
                          M7MMM: ~M7,$M:   . ON.M:MMM
                        ZMM~N$D.N? IN.        ?M M,DMM.
        ?ZMN:         =MO8.M+M M, OM           ,M.M~ZNM:      :~
      87.~MMDM,      M?=8 M,O M+ +O.M    MMM~ .8MZ.M OMMZ     :~MZMZ.
      :M7,          M.ZM 88M.M~ .M.=   ~8.M 7M  NZZZI DM,M.    ..M, M.
                  $O  N .MI 77  M  +O ~M dO.7IM. .O=M. MM,M.     .$OD
                 ~O  M+ 8$  M  ?O     Z8DM?8IO7M   M.M  MM,M
                7~  .8 .M  I+ .M      ZD.7=M :.M   :88+ .+8 8
               ~M   N ~M$ .M .MM      ~M  ~MO  D    M 8  M,M+D.
   .   ?MN.   ~O    M.7$  ?? ?~M       78?M.+MMO    ??$D .O $7I.
    ,M:O?  . ?=    =:O M  M M +$        .           .M M. 8 ++Z~    :M$ .
   .8.I$    7I     MM =M ~MD  7I              IO     ?=,D ,M D~8~     DM
   .MM?    =O     =N  8. ZM   M~        M:   .MM      O M. ?, 8.N~    8NM,.
          $O      M,  O .M.   M        ~MMMMMMMM      O. 7  M .M.M,   .M M
         =8.    .MO.  $.IN IMMM        7MMMMMMMMI     DDZM  =I  M M:   ~D
         D      8N:  .O M==M  M        7MMMMMMMMM     .. MD..M. $= M,
        M      +.M   Z7OM.~8           ,MMMD?MMMD   .ZMMM,Z? ~N  N. M
       D:     $D ?   MZ 8. MM?7?7       +ID ?O:M:  :M: M77.M  8+ :D .M
     .O:    .O+ D.   M  M.+NIZ  7MNMN?I7Z=MMMMMMMDD~   M.8$ : .M  N? ,O
 .?M:MI     8,  M.   M  N M. M. +~ .M.       :M    M    MZ$ M.  D  M  ?M
 78 +I  .  $=  :$  + M. O MIMM. =~  ,O       =M    $,   N:  :8. D~ ,M. :M.
 :,.      ZZ   D .8..M. 8?ZM.M   Z~ ?MZ.     ~O.8$N8OI:~ +   M. .M. +M  .~M+
 .       DI   ?M.M, .Z .8   MMMMMMOI?        ~IMM.. MZ. MN.  +$.  M. M?.  8M
        O8    M M.  .: +=   M   .M ++          $MM:. M~  M7   M   7Z  MM$M. .
       $Z   .7+M    ., +:   N   .M.+M           DM   =N  :O   =M   ZD    MI
    ,  .    .MM     $. ?~  +7.. .M, M          ,NM....M?  D,   M.   N
            MZ      M  I,  M     IM ?=.        Z8M    :M. ,M    D   .M.
           8O      .8  I, ~M      NM MD       ?NO..    ?7  ?~   M.   ID.
                   M,  N. DD      .+M. MM:..:M7MD       M.  M.  M,    I
                   I   M  M, :      .MM  ., .$MI   . : .M?  N+  .
                 M,   .M8M=.           ~NNOZZ~          +M.  M
                .M      M.                        :     .MZ  M=          O,
                ?$      N         ..              ,     ..M  :M.
                N:     ?O   .              .      ,      .D,  NI
```

- [Cathy was an American gag-a-day comic strip](//wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathy)
- [Ack-grep easter egg flags](//gist.github.com/jdwelch/6715cdc98d804550a3e2)

Comment: To be clear about the other two: `ack --bar` shows Admiral Ackbar from Return of the Jedi.  `ack --thpppt` is Bill The Cat from Bloom County.

Comment: Also, note that the `--thpppt` flag is flexible and will work with any option that matches `/^--th[pt]+t+$/`.